How to save container color state in Flutter?
I'm making an app, and in it I have container widgets. I've made these containers stateful, so that when you long tap it, it changes color. The normal color is white24, and when it is long tapped it switches to green. I need help in figuring out how to retain the container's selected color. So, for example, if I make the container green, then when I quit the app and return to that container, it will still be green. I've tried adding a counter of some sort, but that didn't quite work out. I'm relatively new to Flutter, so I don't know what else to try. Thanks in advance!
Here is the code for the stateful container:
class ToolsScreen2State extends State<ToolsScreen2> {
  Color colorContainer = Colors.white24;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SearchPage(),
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Image(
              image: AssetImage(
                'images/Search.png',
              ),
              width: 40,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        title: const Text('Tool Videos'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          InkWell(
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() {
                colorContainer = colorContainer == Colors.white24
                    ? Colors.green.shade600
                    : Colors.white24;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: colorContainer,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/UM.png',
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => launchUrl(Uri.parse(
                          'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRc-uB6IrS4&list=PLNJd3WswnfgMo0suCaTpkNN1Sf8&index=x')),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'UM',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),


You'll need to use some kind of DB to save the color. A simple one to use in these cases is getStorage.
After initializing it as described in the pub.dev page, you could just add a initState like this:
// Using late here allows us to define the value later in initState.
late Color colorContainer;

@override
void initState() {
  // Color can be initialized with an int.
  colorContainer = Color(
    // read method returns null if the key doesn't exist;
    // using "??" allows us to have a default value in case
    // we still haven't saved something to the database.
    GetStorage().read<int>('colorContainer') ?? Colors.white24.value,
  );
}

Then, when changing the container's color, we just have to save the color as an int with the same key we used before.
setState(() {
  colorContainer = colorContainer == Colors.white24
    ? Colors.green.shade600
    : Colors.white24;

  GetStorage().write('colorContainer', colorContainer.value);
});

Again, just make sure to initialize getStorage properly.

How do I initialize the Color with an int in the function you provided? Also, the 'GetStorage().read('colorContainer) ?? Colors.white24' gives me an error that says "The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. " How do I fix this? I think I initalized 'getStorage' correctly.

I also don't know what 'key' you are talking about, I would love some clarification, thanks!

@SpicyPumpkin I forgot to add .value when initializing the Color. I fixed in the answer now, the correct code is GetStorage().read<int>('colorContainer') ?? Colors.white24.value.
The key I'm talking about here is the database key to access the information you want (in this case, the color). I used 'colorContainer' for the key, but it could be anything. The only important part is to use the same string for writing and reading the value.

Thank you for the fixed code, it works perfectly now. Big thanks for the explanation about the key, I understand now. Just one question, will my container now be green if ,on a physical device, I were to quit the app? On the simulator it stays green if I switch through pages, but I can't test if it will stay green after I quit the app.

You're welcome! And yes, getStorage is persistent, what you write to getStorage will be kept between sessions. If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted

Thank you, exactly what I needed. I will mark your answer as accepted, I didn't earlier because I wanted to know if the container will stay green after quitting the app, which it does. Cheers!
